# Is it possible to copy data directly from MySql Local to AWS RDS Cluster Aurora Serverless

Tags: mysql, amazon-web-services, amazon-rds, amazon-aurora

i have a database that i want to move to AWS RDS Amazon Aurora Serverless, i dont have an instance i only have a cluster that i have created which is MySQL Aurora serverless, so is it possible to do a dump from MySQL directly to the cluster instead of dumping to an instance then creating a snapshot to restore on the serverless cluster.

Comment: Try using the AWS migration tool, but make sure your firewall settings allow the connection

Answer (score 2):

We have a service available from Amazon called "DMS" (database Migration Service), there all it needs is the endpoint, connection details of source and target database systems. Here your source is your local DB and target is AWS aurora MySQL DB that you created. It is the simple guide, and you can achieve DB migration by merely following their documentation: check out this link https://docs.aws.amazon.com/dms/latest/sbs/DMS-SBS-Welcome.html

It is almost of no cost for the first user because it offers an instance for free that you can use as a medium for migration.

Comment: The problem i have is when i try to connect to the amazon rds Aurora Serverless cluster database endpoint, the migration schema conversion tool just says connection error: 2018-09-12 11:06:04.906 [  64]      LOADER ERROR   Connection to 'jdbc:mysql://' wasn't established. ERROR: code: 0; message: Communications link failure

Comment: is it possible to migrate the whole database from Amazon RDS PostgreSQL to Amazon Aurora Serverless using DMS?

Answer (score 1):

Connections to Aurora Server less clusters are only available from within the same VPC, they are not publicly accessible.